# Why is the performance of rust tokio so poor? [release test result updated]

Tags: performance, rust, mutex, channel, rust-tokio

The following scenarios are frequently used in asynchronous programming.

- channel tx/rx;
- mutex lock/unlock;
- async task spawn;

So I ran some comparison tests on a lower performance cloud host (equivalent to j1900) as follows. I found that the performance of rust-tokio is very, very poor compared to go-lang.

Is there any parameter that needs to be adjusted? Can a single thread executor improve it?

Results.

- tx/rx, time per op:
  go-lang: 112 ns,

  tokio::sync::mpsc::channel: 7387 ns;

  std::sync::channel: 2705 ns,

  crossbean: 1062 ns.
- mutex lock/unlock, per op:

  tokio::sync::Mutex 4051 ns

  std::sync::Mutex 321 ns
- spawn (not join), per op:

  tokio::spawn: 8445 ns

Rust tokio test tx/rx on channel

```rust
    #[tokio::test]
    async fn test_chan_benchmark() {
        let count = 100_000;
        let (tx, mut rx) = tokio::sync::mpsc::channel(10000);
        let start = std::time::SystemTime::now();
        let handle = tokio::spawn(async move {
            loop {
                let i = rx.recv().await.unwrap();
                if i == count - 1 {
                    break;
                }
            }
        });

        for i in 0..count {
            tx.send(i).await.unwrap();
        }
        drop(tx);

        handle.await.unwrap();
        let stop = std::time::SystemTime::now();
        let dur = stop.duration_since(start).unwrap();
        println!(
            "count={count}, cosume={}ms, ops={}ns",
            dur.as_millis(),
            dur.as_nanos() / count as u128,
        );
    }
```

Go channel tx/rx:

```golang
func TestChanPerformance(t *testing.T) {
    count := 1000000
    ch := make(chan int, count)
    rsp := make(chan int, 1)
    t1 := time.Now()
    go func() {
        for {
            if _, ok := <-ch; !ok {
                rsp <- 0
                break
            }
        }
    }()
    for i := 0; i < count; i++ {
        ch <- i
    }
    close(ch)
    <-rsp

    d := time.Since(t1)
    t.Logf("txrx %d times consumed %d ms, %d nspo", count, d.Milliseconds(), d.Nanoseconds()/int64(count))
}
```

Mutex test:

```rust
    #[tokio::test]
    async fn bench_std_mutex() {
        for count in [1_000, 10_000, 100_000] {
            let start = std::time::SystemTime::now();

            let under = Arc::new(std::sync::Mutex::new(0));
            for _ in 0..count {
                let _ = under.lock().unwrap();
            }

            let stop = std::time::SystemTime::now();
            let dur = stop.duration_since(start).unwrap();
            println!(
                "count={count}, cosume={}ms, ops={}ns",
                dur.as_millis(),
                dur.as_nanos() / count as u128,
            );
        }
    }
```

Tokio spawn test:

```rust
    #[tokio::test]
    async fn bench_tokio_spawn() {
        let count = 100_000;
        //let mut ths = Vec::with_capacity(count);
        let start = std::time::SystemTime::now();
        for _ in 0..count {
            tokio::spawn(async move {});
        }
        let stop = std::time::SystemTime::now();
        let dur = stop.duration_since(start).unwrap();
        //for _ in 0..count {
        //    ths.pop().unwrap().await.unwrap();
        //}
        // do not wait for join, just spawn
        println!(
            "count={count}, cosume={}ms, ops={}ns",
            dur.as_millis(),
            dur.as_nanos() / count as u128,
        );
    }
```

=============UPDATED===========
For --release:

```
std::mpsc::Mutex: 13ns;
tokio::mpsc::Mutex: 130ns;
std::mpsc::channel: 200ns;
tokio::mpsc::channel: 256ns;
tokio::spawn: 553ns;
```

Comment: Did you compile in `--release` mode?

Comment: It is really hard to believe that the RELEASE parameter brings such a big improvement, for the sending and receiving of channels, from 7387 ns down to 257 ns, bringing a tens of times improvement. Thank you very much @SvenMarnach

Comment: `tokio::test` uses single threaded runtime by default. It'd be better to write a `bench`, instead of tests

Comment: @progquester That's the whole point of the `--release` parameter. Rust debug performs almost no optimizations at all. This kind of speedup is normal and expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `--release` to instruct the compiler to perform optimizations.

To demonstrate just *how* much of a difference this makes, here is a simple `add` function compiled with and without optimizations:

```rust
pub fn add(a: u32, b: u32) -> u32 {
    a + b
}
```

- [with optimizations](https://rust.godbolt.org/z/r1b11vqh6):

```
example::add:
        lea     eax, [rdi + rsi]
        ret
```

- [without optimizations](https://rust.godbolt.org/z/Ezend7oan):

```
example::add:
        push    rax
        add     edi, esi
        mov     dword ptr [rsp + 4], edi
        setb    al
        test    al, 1
        jne     .LBB0_2
        mov     eax, dword ptr [rsp + 4]
        pop     rcx
        ret
.LBB0_2:
        lea     rdi, [rip + str.0]
        lea     rdx, [rip + .L__unnamed_1]
        mov     rax, qword ptr [rip + core::panicking::panic@GOTPCREL]
        mov     esi, 28
        call    rax
        ud2

.L__unnamed_2:
        .ascii  "/app/example.rs"

.L__unnamed_1:
        .quad   .L__unnamed_2
        .asciz  "\017\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\002\000\000\000\005\000\000"

str.0:
        .ascii  "attempt to add with overflow"
```

Note that the optimized version does no longer contain an overflow check. The overflow check is very useful during debugging, but also very slow.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Rust compiles programs in debug mode with no optimizations, so you get big binaries and low performance.

Try to compile it with the next profile (put it into `Cargo.toml`) and `-r` flag:

```ini
[profile.release]
opt-level = 3
strip = true
debug = false
codegen-units = 1
lto = true
```

Command:
`cargo build -r`