# How to resolve problem about future cannot be sent between threads safely without tokio-mutex and channel?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I know this question has been asked by many people, and in the past, either tokio::sync::Mutex was recommended to replace std::sync::Mutex, or it was made to be called in the same task via Channel.

What I want to know is if there is any other way to do this? In the case of my current TcpStream send.

```rust
#[tokio::test]
async fn test_send_arc_mutex_tcps() {
    async fn one(tcps: Arc<std::sync::Mutex<TcpStream>>, src: String) {
        tcps.lock().unwrap().write(src.as_bytes()).await.unwrap();
        //--------------------                      ^^^^^^ await occurs here, with `tcps.lock().unwrap()` maybe used later
        // |
        // has type `std::sync::MutexGuard<'_, tokio::net::TcpStream>` which is not `Send`
    }

    async fn two(tcps: Arc<std::sync::Mutex<TcpStream>>, src: String) {
        let w = {
            let mut tcps = tcps.lock().unwrap();
            tcps.write(src.as_bytes()) // `tcps` does not live long enough
                                       // borrowed value does not live long enough
        };
        let _ = w.await;
    }

    let tcps = TcpStream::connect("192.168.1.10:8080").await.unwrap();
    let tcps = Arc::new(std::sync::Mutex::new(tcps));
    let datum = [
        "hello".to_string(),
        "rustl".to_string(),
        "tokio".to_string(),
    ];
    for data in datum.iter() {
        let tcps1 = tcps.clone();
        let tcps2 = tcps.clone();
        let data1 = data.clone();
        let data2 = data.clone();
        tokio::spawn(async move {
            // error: future cannot be sent between threads safely
            one(tcps1, data1).await;
            two(tcps2, data2).await;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: It would help if you could explain why the solutions that you've already discovered are unsuitable for you?

Comment: @eggyal thank you. It is about performance. tokio::sync::mutex and channel have a bad performance according to my test.

Comment: Nit: you probably want `write_all()`.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Thank you. But why do you think `write_all()` can resolve it? I replaced it, but no help.

Comment: It does not, that's why I wrote "Nit". It's an unrelated fact.

Comment: I thought of it as “Hit”， :), Thank you anyway!

Comment: _"`tokio::sync::Mutex` has a bad performance"_ when compared with what? Are you sure that the performance issues you're seeing come frome the tokio mutex and not from some other aspect of your test?

Comment: Also, please provide a [mre]. Your code has errors that are completely unrelated to your question.

Comment: @Jmb compared with `std::sync::mutex`. Even though the direct replacement into std::sync::mutex does not compile, from the results of our specially constructed tests, std::sync::mutex takes only about 10ns, but tokio::sync::mutex takes almost 200ns. I understand that tokio::sync::mutex does more, but the difference is indeed too big. golang is much more advantageous in this regard. Maybe this piece is not all the bottleneck, but 200ns is obviously a definite improvement if it can be optimized to within 50ns. This piece is one of the highest frequency calls of the program.

Comment: The options laid out before your are your best options. Even if std::sync::mutex were allowed to be held across awaits you wouldn't want to use it anyway since it could easily tank your performance elsewhere if you have any amount of lock contention. Asynchronous Rust is a cooperative multitasking model; if you don't cooperate with the whole system by avoiding blocking calls (like waiting on some other write) then you're going to have a bad time.

Comment: I was curious about the actual performance difference, because the tokio mutex does have to do a bit more work, but the difference was only 20ns on my system (in a non-contentious synthetic test of course).

Comment: @kmdreko Could you show me your code? Here is my test code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73770247

Comment: [Here's](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=48d17316c2f652d98eed37197cd00d83) essentially what I tested with. The playground is getting 10ms and 48ms respectively for me (not the same as my local system but still not 200ns difference). Hopefully its a valid demonstration.